# Read inside an if statement and buffer type

Tags: c

I just want to know how to following code works. I am trying to open a file and reading it using the read() function. However, I also want to check if the read is successful.

Does the code below execute read() twice? By that, I mean, does the buffer have 1024 bytes of data inside it after the code executes? Or does it only have 512 bytes of data because only the first executed and the read inside the if statement only check the value but does not really write into the buffer. Also, I'm reading raw bits into the buffer. Am I using the right buffer type? I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. Thanks in advance!

```
//Read the file
void *buffer;
read(fd,buffer,512);
if (read(fd,buffer,512) < 0){
    printf("Error: Read was unsuccessful \n");
}
else{
    printf("Read is successful \n" );
}
```

Comment: why don't you check the return value of `read`. ?

Comment: Yes. Your code calls `read` twice.

Comment: Hi, can you please show me an example on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What does `fd` refer to: a file, a socket, a pipe?

Comment: fd refers to file descriptor from the open() function. It is reading a fat12 .dat file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `read(fd,buffer,512)` is called twice. If you wish to use the return value more than once, store it in a variable – calling the same function again, even with the same arguments, is distinct from the previous call. In general, functions in C can have *side-effects* so multiple calls to the same function with the same arguments can not be optimized away (e.g., the side-effect of `read` is reading data from the descriptor into the buffer, and indeed calling `read` is done more for the fact that it reads than for sake of the value it returns).

Meanwhile if your code is complete as shown, the use of `buffer` is invalid since it's uninitialized.

Assuming `buffer` does point to an actual buffer capable of holding the data, a maximum of 512 bytes would be stored there by `read`. Since you don't change where `buffer` points to between the calls to `read`, the same buffer would be overwritten by the second `read`. (Note that there is no guarantee that all 512 bytes requested, or indeed any bytes, will actually be read - the return value of `read` tells you how many bytes were actually read.)

Comment: How would I initialize it? Can you please show me? I mainly do Java, so I am not really familiar with C. Thanks!

Comment: @user2989964 Well, `buffer = malloc(512)` would allocate the necessary 512 bytes on the heap, but then you have to `free(buffer)` exactly once after nothing uses that memory anymore. Or you can replace the pointer with something like `char buffer[512]` to place it on the stack.

Comment: Is void an acceptable type for handling raw bits? I never used void before so I am not sure. If not, what would you suggest? I have to make sure that I am not treating the data as ASCII. Thanks!

Comment: @user2989964 A void pointer can point to any type of data. You cannot dereference the void pointer without casting it to something else, so when you actually access the data you must decide on some data type, e.g., `uint8_t` (or `unsigned char`) for raw bytes as unsigned integers.

Comment: Would unsigned char convert the data into ASCII? I'm thinking of using the size_t type. Would that work? Also, in what form can I expect the raw bytes to be in? Would they be in hex or binary? Thanks!

Comment: @user2989964 The data is never converted to anything by the type of pointer you use to access it. Also I don't know why you think that `unsigned char` has something to do with ASCII, it is just a type of integer (indeed almost certainly the same type a `uint8_t`, so use that if the `char` in the name troubles you =). If you access the data through a `size_t *` pointer, then the data you read in must already consist of integers of the `size_t` type in the format for your machine.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Last question. I intend to convert the raw bytes/bits into decimal numbers so that I can view their values. Do you have any idea on how to do this? I'm thinking of taking your advice and use `unsigned char` instead of `size_t`. I tried strtol before and it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: @user2989964 If you mean the values of each byte read (e.g., file has bytes 0x01 0x02 0x03 and you want values 1, 2, and 3), they are already there when you access the individual bytes (e.g., as `uint8_t`). Not decimal, of course, but binary.

Comment: So if I access buffer[11], I can expect the data to be something like 1101 0110? Or will it be in hex? Thanks!

Comment: @user2989964 It will be an integer. If you choose to print it out as decimal or hexadecimal, it is up to you. 0b11010110, 214 decimal, and 0xD6 are all the same integer. (In any case, this is going so far off the original question that you should probably ask another one. And if my answers have helped you with regard to your original question here, please accept the answer.)

Comment: Ok, I will ask another question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The `read()` function get executed twice. For checking the condition in `if` statement

```
if (read(fd,buffer,512) < 0){  
     ...
```

`read(fd,buffer,512)` read again the data ignoring the previous one.

> does the buffer have 1024 bytes of data inside it after the code executes

No. Second call to `read` will overwrite the data inside the buffer.
And one more thing is that you program's behavior is **undefined**. This is because you are using `buffer` without initializing it. You can use `malloc` function to allocate memory to your `buffer`

```
buffer = malloc(512);
```

Comment: How about the buffer type? Is void an acceptable type for raw bits? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You not initialize `buffer` pointer and use it. It is undefined behaviour. `read()` executes twice, and buffer can contain 1024 bytes if buffer initialized before. But it's possible that `read()` read only partial of 512 bytes.

Comment: Two calls to read might read 512+512 bytes, but the 2nd read would overwrite the 1st. So it ends up with 512. The buffer will never contain more.